# Migrating MySQL data from a legacy PHP application to a Rails application

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently rebuilding a legacy application in Rails. The legacy application is based on PHP and uses a MySQL database.

The main challenge thus far is migrating the data across and conforming to a structure that is suitable for Rails.

The legacy PHP app has many tables with most having an identical column structure, the only exception being a couple of tables with additional columns. The reason for the separation is the data is being inserted by many different scripts, so just for troubleshooting/safety they are all split up.

What is the best way to transition this data across to Ruby on Rails?

Comment: what have you tried?  Is there a reason you can't leave it as is?  Are you looking to merge all the tables w identical structure?  If so, how to merge them will depend on what you have vs what you need... not a question that can be answered with what you've provided so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would replicate / use the exact db as is, switch to Rails front-end and start verifying.  Assuming you are using `ActiveRecord`, you can easily overcome the issues of default primary key (`id`), foreign key by using something like this:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'your old table / replicated table'
  self.primary_key = 'your old primary key'
  ...
end
```

Associations can be specified as below

```
...
  belongs_to :something, :foreign_key => 'old foreign key', :primary_key => 'pri_key'
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Bala 
Would you recommend having the one model for all these tables with the same column structure?